# Replace cell references with string from a corresponding cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells with calculations.

Here is one simple example, which is in row 11.

```
=$V11*$AB11*AF11
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
=[EAD: On Balance Sheet]*[PD Low]*[Collateral LGD High]
```

These 3 strings all come from row 10, in Column V, AB, and AF.

Here is another example:

Change this:

```
=$V11*VLOOKUP($AA11,Rates!AQ:AU,5,FALSE)*AE11
```

To this:

```
'[EAD: On Balance Sheet]*VLOOKUP([Proposed Risk Rating],Rates!AQ:AU,5,FALSE)*[Collateral LGD Low]
```

All formulas are on row 11, and I want to get the corresponding headers, which are all strings, from row 10.

I'm thinking that there must be a way to do this, since Excel knows all the relevant cell references, and keeps track of everything.

I can't figure out how to replace the reference with the string (in this case the corresponding header in row 10).

Comment: Are you looking to setup named ranges? Is your data in a table? A little more detail as to the significance of the named entities would help here.

Comment: Writing an application to parse Excel formulas and determine which bits are cell references (and therefore need to be changed) and which bits are operators, and which bits are named ranges, and which bits are function names, etc, will not be a trivial exercise.  You also need to consider what you want to happen if the formula was, for instance, `=SUM($AB11:$AF11)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this so don't have enough 'reputation' to comment and clarify your question. 
If the cells V11, AB11 and AF11 have the text "EAD: On Balance Sheet", "PD Low " and "Collateral LGD High" and you want this cell to show those words.
Then the following code could work:

```
sub combine_words()
dim i as string
dim j as string
dim k as string

i = range("V11").value
j = range("AB11").value
k = range("AF11").value

range("A11").value = "[" & i & "]*[" & j & "]*[" & k & "]"

end sub
```

replace the cell A11 with whichever cell you wanted the text inputed into.

Let me know if I understood your question incorrectly and I will change the code to match your needs if I can.

Comment: Rohan, it's not that easy.  I just updated my original post.  I'm trying to pick out the cell references in row 11 and replace them with strings (headers from an Access table) which all sit in row 10.  Any thoughts?  This seems to be somewhat tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple find and replace in the formula would work well enough. I'm sure there are *lots* of edge cases I'm not thinking about. Hopefully this steers the conversation in the right direction.

```
Sub SOExample()
    Dim mySheet         As Worksheet: Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim headerRng       As Range: Set headerRng = mySheet.Range("A1:J1") 'Specify where to do replacements
    Dim mycell          As Range
    Dim vkey            As Variant
    Dim myDict          As Object: Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Iterate each header row add the address as the key, and the NEXT row's Text as the value
    For Each mycell In headerRng
        If Not myDict.exists(mycell.Offset(1, 0).Address) Then
            myDict.Add mycell.Offset(1, 0).Address, mycell.Text
        End If
    Next

    'Iterate each cells formula and replace it
    For Each mycell In headerRng
        For Each vkey In myDict.keys
            mycell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = Replace(mycell.Offset(1, 0).Formula, vkey, myDict(vkey), , , vbTextCompare)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, Ryan, that works in one specific example.  I need to loop through a couple hundred cells in M11:GZ11, find multiple references in each cell, and replace all references with the relative strings in row 10.  Here is one more example: =ABS(DQ11+DT11) --> =ABS([Base+Imprecision]+[Concentration Risk]).  So, DQ10=[Base+Imprecision] and DT10=[Concentration Risk].

Comment: Can you iterate over the header row and add the header as the key and the address of the offset cell as the value into the dict?

Comment: Sounds good to me, but I don't know how to do that.  I think I need to parse through the cell addresses, and replace each one with the header, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: See my edited answer, see if that is getting closer.